# Nuxt : Check route is redirected from other routes or directly load?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm face up with a problem when login.

If user is authenticated, I will let them redirect to home page.

And if they come from another protected route (homepage, other routes) and after logined, I want it redirect to exactly the route they came from.

My solution is:

- In auth.js middleware, I will save to cookie the route they come from like this

  ```
  app.$cookie.set("historyRoute", app.router.history.current.path)
  ```
- In `login.vue` I will check if exist `historyRoute` to let them redirect then remove  `historyRoute` from cookie.

But problem is that user will come from other protected routes and they do not take login action at that time, they make refreshing Login page many times and `historyRoute` will still exist in cookie.

So I want to know how to determine when visitors directly reload Login page to remove `historyRoute` in cookie.

Or if you have another solution, please suggest me know. Thanks.

Update flow:

Visitor access link `/users/setting`

```
-> check Auth
-> if Not Auth 
   -> redirect 302 to /Login
   -> After login (I need to know they directly come from login page or from /user/setting then redirect to login page)
   -> redirect back to users/setting
```

Comment: I'm not sure to fully understand what is your issue here, but you may maybe try `this.$router.history._startLocation`, this one will give the path the users arrives on when initial accessing the given page (either with a `href` follow or a `F5` page refresh).

Comment: @kissu I tried with your suggest but I can't access history route with redirect. Can you check my update question. Thank you so much.